# iPhone: removing objects from page

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIView which has a 'display' method I wrote.
In the 'display' method, I have the following code:
First, create a main view

```
UIView *contentView = ...
```

Second, create lots of objects, like this:

```
ObjectView* objectView = ... (ObjectView is also a UIView)
```

Third, add all these objects to the contentView, like this:

```
[contentView addSubview:objectView];
```

Finally, I add contentView to self.

Initially, the 'display' method is called from 'initWithFrame', and it all displays as I want. I also have a view which when clicked also calls the 'display' method, this time it should display new content. The problem is that the new content displays over the original content, the original content is not removed.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the old subview like this:

```
[[contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Either that or remove `contentView` from self, before adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You should make these objects properties of your viewController, so you can set them however you want whenever you want:
in the header:

```
ObjectView *objectview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ObjectView *objectview;
```

int the .m

```
@synthesize objectview;
```

then you can set the properties of objectview anywhere you want.

```
objectview.label.text = @"some text"; //just an example
```